# Does MongoDB use indexes after root replacement?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I use following aggregation pipline:

```js
db.myCollection.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "x": {
                "$lte": 100
            }
        }
    }, {
        "$sort": {
            "x": -1
        }
    }, {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "y": "$y",
                "z": "$z"
            },
            "r": {
                "$first": "$$CURRENT"
            }
        }
    }, {
        "$replaceRoot": {
            "newRoot": "$r"
        }
    }, {
        "$match": {
            "a": true,
            "b": "value"
        }
    }
]);
```

Obviously, it's possible to improve performance of the query by adding following index:

```js
db.myCollection.createIndex({ x: -1 });
```

The documentation [says](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#-group-performance-optimizations) the `$group` stage will not use indexes, because it groups by another field then `$match` and `$sort` stages. Am I right, or is it possible to add `x` and `y` fields to the first index to use one?

And, please, help me to understand: can the MongoDB use indexes after `$replaceRoot` stage? Will it improve performance if I add the following index?

```js
db.myCollection.createIndex({ a: 1, b: 1 });
```

Comment: You should put `{ $match: { a: true, b: "value" }` at the top. Index is not used after `$replaceRoot`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, it will break the business logic. It is necessary to check `a` and `b` only for the first element of group. Otherwise I can get unnecessary elements.

Comment: How can this be? Then put `$match: { a: true, b: "value" }` at the beginning (with index on `{x: -1, a: 1, b: 1}`) to limit the number of documents and once again at the end.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, for example `$group` returns only one group. `$match: { a: true, b: "value" }` can exclude element, which would be first. So, as result, I will get second  or third element instead of empty result.

Comment: Are you sure? Do you have an example?

Comment: I think [this playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BUGxQSd8gF9) with the original aggregation and then [this playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/chf5lf89Sj2) with the same data but your proposed rewrite demonstrates the business logic breakage @WernfriedDomscheit. Notice there is no data returned with the first pipeline but there is with the second meaning they are not logically equivalent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've asked two different questions here. This answer will focus mostly on the question in the title which is about index usage in a `$match` stage that follows a `$replaceRoot`.

The answer to that question is: no, an index cannot help here in your particular case.

Keep in mind that indexes are used to efficiently find documents in the collection. But after the `$group` stage here (and therefore the `$replaceRoot` as well) you no longer have the original documents. Instead you have synthesized something new. The database is going to operate on those new items after that point, therefore there would generally be no benefit (or even ability) to go back to the collection to begin scanning source documents once again.

There is potentially a special case when the `$match` predicates are on fields used during the grouping. However that does not apply in this case either. You [confirmed in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75684665/does-mongodb-use-indexes-after-root-replacement#comment133520759_75684665) that you cannot manually pull the trailing `$match` stage earlier as it would break the business logic. This is the same reason that the database would be unable to do so as it is not allowed to perform any optimization that would logically change the results requested by the client.

As for you other question about index usage for `$group` itself, last I checked the optimization you linked was not applicable for grouping on compound values as you have in your example. You could try creating a compound index on all three fields (`{ x: 1, y: 1, z: 1 }`) and see if the `.explain()` output shows a plan with a `DISTINCT_SCAN` on the version that you are using. Even if so it might not necessarily be faster depending on how many unique values there are for `y` and `z`.

Comment: The $group stage needs the entire document to evaluate "$$SURRENT", so the query cannot be satisfied with a DISTINCT_SCAN

Comment: You upset me, but I thank you for the useful answer ;-)

Comment: @Joe: A `DISTINCT_SCAN` plan is _not_ necessarily a [covered query](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query). That stage is referring to how the database will jump around in the index rather than stating that a `FETCH` won't be performed. The output is wonky to read, but you can see [this playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Iqp4GWRNUCp) demonstrates a plan that includes both `DISTINCT_SCAN` and `FETCH` stages

Comment: Interesting, that's a new optimization